# Calling a function between components

Tags: angular6

I have two components(comp1 and comp2). I am trying to call a function which is inside comp1 from comp2 and it is not happening and it is throwing an error. But it is successful when calling a function inside comp2 from comp1.

I want it to happen in both the ways
(i.e)
(a) function trigger from comp2 inside comp1
(b)function trigger from comp1 inside comp2

I have attached the sample code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxfzqb

Answer (score 0):

The error is throwing from constructor function on comp1, it cant generate a new instance of comp2.

Please try not use provides of components between components, i suggest you make getting binding components from app.component to comp1 and comp2, example:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-comp1 #comp1 [Comp2Component]="comp2"></app-comp1>
<app-comp2 #comp2 [Comp1Component]="comp1"></app-comp2>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Comp1Component } from './comp1/comp1.component';
import { Comp2Component } from './comp1/comp2/comp2.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  // Get component with attr #comp1
  @ViewChild('comp1') comp1: Comp1Component;
  // Get component with attr #comp2
  @ViewChild('comp2') comp2: Comp2Component;
}
```

**comp1.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp1',
  templateUrl: './comp1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp1.component.css']
})
export class Comp1Component implements OnInit {
  @Input() Comp2Component: Comp2Component;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  funcInComp1() {
    console.log("comp1 function triggered from comp2");
  }

  triggerComp2Function() {
    this.Comp2Component.funcInComp2();
  }
}
```

**comp2.component.ts**

```
import { Input, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Comp1Component } from '../comp1.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp2',
  templateUrl: './comp2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp2.component.css']
})
export class Comp2Component implements OnInit {
  @Input() Comp1Component: Comp1Component

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  triggerComp1Function() {
    this.Comp1Component.funcInComp1();
  }
  funcInComp2() {
    console.log("comp2 function triggered from comp1");
  }
}
```

stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itmzhe